# Can the Dragonwrought feat be used as draconic heritage?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, sorcerer, dragons, feat-qualifications

I'm planning on playing a sorcerer kobold, and I want to know whether the Dragonwrought feat from *Races of the Dragon* (pg. 100) can replace the draconic heritage prerequisites for both other draconic feats and for class entry requirements? (Specifically, Dragonheart Mage.)

Comment: the game system/edition is D&D 3.5

Comment: the book where there is the class and feat is the Races of the dragon

Answer (score 2):

No. Draconian Heritage is a specific feat which sorcerers can take at first level. Even a normal chromatic or metallic dragon would have to take that feat before taking levels in Dragonheart Mage.

Answer (score 2):

Kobold also Automatically qualify for Dragonblood Sorcerer substitution levels. (Same book as dragonwrought, page 107), level 1 substitution is Draconic Heritage as a class feature, it replaces your familiar (instead of using up a feat.) Meaning you can do both Dragonwrought and Draconic Heritage that way.

Answer (score 1):

Actually... Dragonwrought does allow you to take certain draconic feats, PRCs, etc. Not by acting as a stand in for the Draconic Heritage feat, but by changing your type to Dragon. Regardless of the "are dragonwrought kobolds true dragons" debate, ANYTHING with the dragon type automatically qualifies for feats that require the dragonblood type. This is one reason Dragonwrought is such a powerful feat.

I quote -

> The dragonblood subtype does not confer the dragon type or any traits associated with that type. For instance, it does not give a creature frightful presence. Dragons automatically qualify for any classes, prestige classes, racial substitution levels, feats, powers, or spells that require the dragonblood subtype.

Thus, in becoming a dragonwrought kobold, you qualify for feats like Dragon Wings, but due to Dragonheart Mage not requiring the dragonblood subtype and instead specifically requiring the Draconic Heritage feat, you'd still need the feat to get into the class.

I don't see why you couldn't take both Dragonwrought and Draconic Heritage at level 1, to give yourself the dragon type and then regain the dragonblood subtype as well. It's a feat tax, but hey, at least you automatically qualify for a bunch of other sweet stuff!

Comment: The typical kobold sorcerer has no way of taking two feats at 1st level, so that would be one reason you couldn’t. They could take Draconic Heritage at 3rd, though, since the Draconic Heritage requirement is “sorcerer level 1st” rather than “sorcerer level 1st *only*” as Dragonwrought has for character level.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is No.
Even though it may seen redundant because of the benefits of the feat it does not allow you to surpass the pre requisite of having said feat even if you are in fact a true dragon.

BUT, as a DM I would rule this out because it probably wasn't thought about that case when the feat and prestige class were developed.

Comment: Dragonheart mage was printed in the same book as Dragonwrought, though...

Comment: Which is pretty ironic, but such holes exist everywhere in the system